# Mysql find out for each rider what their longest unbroken run of wins was

Tags: mysql

I have a table called riders with riders information in it, the structure is as follows

```
id |time_of_ride |rider |Results
 1 |08:12:16     |Gavin | Wins
 2 |08:12:31     |Gavin | Wins
 3 |08:12:40     |Louis | Loose
 4 |09:12:31     |Gavin | Wins
 5 |10:12:31     |Gavin | Wins
```

I would like to find out for each rider what their longest unbroken run of wins was. such that the results could be like as follows.

```
Rider       Wins
Gavin       2
```

Comment: how do calculate the longest unbroken run ? in your table Gavin wins 4 times why you get 2 in your output ? explain more

Comment: Remember, Stackoverflow doesn't exist to write your code. We need examples on what you did so we can give you some examples or push you into the right direction.

Comment: Sorry about that , that was supposed to be Gavin with a loose I'll try to update it soon . I have done a lot of research and written my SQL code  but it wasn't even close it's not worth sharing here it will confuse more than guide you

Comment: so what you need to know is sum of rider's win ?

Comment: The longest unbroken wins . Say a rider rides 10 rides in a day and wins the first 3 rides , and the last 4 rides and looses the other so the unbroken record here would 4

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and a specific question.

Comment: This is known as an island and gap problem. search for it and mySQL and I'm sure you'll find a few dozen good examples.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a cursor to loop over each rider's series of results and count the wins until you find a loss :

```
DECLARE win_count INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE max_wins INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE result varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

DECLARE wins_cursor CURSOR FOR 
SELECT Results FROM TABLE where rider = Gavin;

OPEN wins_cursor;

LOOP

 FETCH wins_cursor INTO result;

 IF result = "Wins" THEN 
     SET win_count = win_count + 1;
 ELSE
     IF win_count > max_wins THEN
         SET max_wins = win_count;
     END IF;
     SET win_count = 0;
 END IF;



END LOOP;

CLOSE wins_cursor;
```

You'll need to adapt this code to return the value, and maybe add another cursor around it to loop on all your riders but you get the idea.

Edit : Added variable to save the max number of wins.

Comment: this looks good , but there wont be an input from the user the sql should do the calculations and comparison for each user

Comment: Like I said, you should adapt this code to fit your needs. It's not too hard to add another cursor to find the values for all the riders, and compare them at the end. You'll also need to put all the code in a stored procedure, from which you'll return your expected output. I'm pretty sure you could also find complete examples with a couple google searches.